# react native fbsdk setup build errors

Tags: android, facebook, react-native, fbsdk, react-native-fbsdk

I have done all the settings that are given in this [link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) and also this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/). But I am getting the following errors when I try to run my project,

```
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainActivity.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class MainActivity
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
                   ^
  symbol:   class CallbackManager
  location: package com.facebook
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
                   ^
  symbol:   class FacebookSdk
  location: package com.facebook
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:13: error: package com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk does not exist
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
                                          ^
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:14: error: package com.facebook.appevents does not exist
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
                             ^
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                 ^
  symbol:   class CallbackManager
  location: class MainApplication
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
  protected static CallbackManager getCallbackManager() {
                   ^
  symbol:   class CallbackManager
  location: class MainApplication
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:21: error: package CallbackManager does not exist
  private static CallbackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                                                                   ^
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
          new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
              ^
  symbol: class FBSDKPackage
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    ^
  symbol:   variable FacebookSdk
  location: class MainApplication
/mnt/2EB2BF06B2BED217/Freelancing/yasco/sg/saZen/mobile/sazenappmobile/SaZen/android/app/src/main/java/com/sazen/MainApplication.java:54: error: cannot find symbol
    AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
    ^
  symbol:   variable AppEventsLogger
  location: class MainApplication
11 errors
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

Currently I am using "16.0.0-alpha.12" version of react.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final version of my gradle, which worked for me, looks like below,

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
...
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

Observe these lines in the dependencies,

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

and the compileSDKVersion must same as the support and hence it must be,

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
```

These were the main things which held me for these many days.

Answer (score 3):

My project compiles with the latest package versions, using buildToolsVersion 25.0.3

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
```

build.gradle defaultConfig

```
targetSdkVersion 25
```

build.gradle dependencies

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.3"
```

The documentation says

> If your react-native version is below 0.29.0

but it throws error saying cannot find symbol Intent so...

MainActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using the latest react-native downgrade to 0.46.4, the latest version has some breaking changes that affect many native packages.

Also use react-native-fbsdk@0.6.0 as it is still compiled with buildToolsVersion 23

Follow the steps again and it should work

I spend quite a few hours recently trying to make this work and only downgrading to these version solved the issues I was encountering.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried degrading the version and then tried the steps mentioned in the above mentioned link. But still stumbling into the same issue. I strongly feel I am missing some step. I am not getting what wrong I am doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import android.content.Intent in MainActivity.java:

```
import android.content.Intent;
```

in MainApplication.java:

```
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
```